# How to write Swift generic functions of enum types?

Tags: class, generics, enums, swift, protocols

Using Swift, I want to write a protocol that specifies that implementing classes must have a function that takes an enum (which adheres to a given protocol), where that enum type is specified generically. I've tried this:

```
protocol Message {}

protocol Subscriber {
  func receive<T where T:Message>(message:T)
}

enum Greeting : Message {
  case Hello, Goodbye
}

class SomeObject : Subscriber {
  func receive<Greeting>(message: Greeting) {
    switch message {
    case .Hello:
      println("Hello")
    case .Goodbye:
      println("Goodbye")
    }
  }
}
```

This fails to compile with the message "Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'Greeting'" at each of the case lines. This would appear to be because the Subscriber protocol expects something that is no more specialized than Message, but I set things up in terms of Greeting, which though it implements Message, is more specialized. (Am I right?)

So, how do I do what I'm attempting to do, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The generic type parameter `T` should still be generic in the implementation of `Subscriber`.
You can do what you ask using a `typealias` in `protocol Subscriber` and enforce the `Message` superclass constraint on it:

```
protocol Message {}

protocol Subscriber {
    typealias MessageType: Message
    func receive (message: MessageType)
}

enum Greeting : Message {
    case Hello, Goodbye
}

class SomeObject : Subscriber {
    typealias MessageType = Greeting

    func receive (message: MessageType) {
        switch message {
        case .Hello:
            println("Hello")
        case .Goodbye:
            println("Goodbye")
        }
    }
}
```

Having a generic `receive` prevents you from switching on the `enum` fields:

```
protocol Message {}

protocol Subscriber {
    func receive <T: Message> (message: T)
}

enum Greeting : Message {
    case Hello, Goodbye
}

class SomeObject : Subscriber {
    func receive <T: Message> (message: T) {

    }
}

let obj = SomeObject()
obj.receive(Greeting.Hello)
```

Comment: Your answer is totally correct, but I think in beta 5 Apple has flip-flopped what kinds of things should be `FooType` vs. `Foo` (i.e., `Dictionary` now has `Key` and `Value` instead of `KeyType` and `ValueType`, whereas `Sequence` is now `SequenceType`). They're not 100% consistent about it, but `Message` and `MessageType` in your answer seem reversed in that context.

Comment: You're right, I used `MessageType` to use the same class names Chris used in his question.

Comment: Ack! Of course. @Chris, that was meant for you... :\

Comment: Thanks, @pNre. But unless I'm misunderstanding, your solution is not longer generic. Did you mean in saying "type parameter T should still be generic" that in theory it is but Swift isn't (yet?) doing that?

Comment: I mean that when you instance `SomeObject` you can't assign a `Message` type but you are bound to `Greeting`. Do you want every instance of `SomeObject` to use a different type in `receive`? In that case you won't be able to switch on `message` since `Hello` and `Goodbye` are `Greeting` fields.

Comment: Yes, I want the receive function to be generic in its type.

Comment: I've updated the answer (but I'm under the impression I didn't completely get what you're asking).